# Price in layered navigation dropdown not in sequence

Tags: price, layered-navigation, magento-1.5.1

I am getting issue in price dropdown in layered navigation. It is displaying as below 
[image: price not in correct order] 
But it should appear in order like 
10 - 20 
20 - 30 
30 - 40 
40 - 50 
But as you can see, it is not at all in order and I am not getting from where I should start debugging. 
Please let me know if anybody face this type of issue earlier and give some guidance in fixing this and what can be the issue?
Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The price filter layer is generated here: `Mage_Catalog_Model_Layer_Filter_Price`

I would assume the error occurs here: `\Mage_Catalog_Model_Layer_Filter_Price::_getItemsData` but I have no idea. Wherever it happens, this class should be the right one.

Comment: Thanks, I just sorted $dbRanges in _getItemsData and it is fixed. But I just want to know if it is a default Magento issue or there ca be some other issue which is doing this? Do you have any idea. I havn't seen something like this before.

Comment: I *think* magento generates the ranges ordered, so this is NO issue in a vanilla magento.